# Grafana Alerts when working with CloudWatch Logs Insights

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, grafana-alerts

The following is how my query looks like ( Basically tracking 5xx errors ) :

[image]

Now, I would ideally want an alert whenever a “ERROR …” is logged by my system (5xx error ).

This is my alert condition :

[image]

Alerts work fine but I would want more information like what is the **error message** in the alert itself.

Is there anything I could do to make my alert message more verbose? I would ideally want to send fields like timestamp and message in the notification itself.

Comment: Hey! What's the version of Grafana you're using? I'm having the same issue. Thanks!